# How to load all YouTube videos with volume muted?

Tags: youtube, mute

I spend more time on the computer/internet than on anything else (I know, I know!). Now, I do watch a lot of YouTube videos, but in order to not get distracted I have to launch them with the volume muted, that is, all the videos I launch should be launched with volume muted.

And when I am done with my work, I will play the videos by manually increasing the volume.

Is there any way I can ensure that the YouTube videos are all launched with the volume muted?

Note: Muting the laptop/desktop volume is not an acceptable answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows(*) you can mute an application. In your case, you could mute the browser you are using to watch the videos.

I don't know if this feature is present in other OSs and how it works.

[image]

(*): I'm using Vista